# Using Cloud Function Default Service Account to Access The Gmail API

Tags: python, gmail, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

I don't know what this is so confusing for me. I have the following code to access the gmail api from a cloud function. It works. The issue is that I am using a json file of credentials for the app engine service account. But, this is the default service account for cloud functions, so shouldn't I be able to somehow accomplish the same task without needing to use the credential files?

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject("my.email@email.com")

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials, cache_discovery=False)
```

I have tried

```
from google.auth import compute_engine

credentials = compute_engine.Credentials()
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused by your question, so you are using the default service account for GCF and it works fine, but when you use the default service account for GAE you get an error? Also, what is the issue you are facing, are you getting any error message of some sort?